# $Int(\overline{U\cap M})=Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M})$ for any U open in X

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $Int(\overline{U\cap M})=Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M})$ for any U open in X

1) To prove that $Int(\overline{U\cap M}) \subseteq Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M})$ I used that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$ and $Int(A\cap B)=Int(A)\cap Int(B) $ for any $A,B\subseteq X$.

Since $\overline{U\cap M}\subseteq\overline{U}\cap\overline{M},$ we get that $Int(\overline{U\cap M}) \subseteq Int(\overline{U}\cap\overline{M})=Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M}) $

2)To prove the inverse inclusion,  $Int(\overline{U\cap M}) \supseteq Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M})$ I tried to use that a point $x\in Int(A)\iff\exists U\text{ open in }X \text{ such that }x\in U\subseteq A$.

Let $x\in Int(\overline{U})\cap Int(\overline{M}).$ So $x\in Int(\overline{U})\text{ and }x\in Int(\overline{M}).$ There exist two neighbourhoods $W_{1}, W_{2}$ of $x$ such that $x\in W_{1}\subseteq \overline{U} \text{ and } x\in W_{2}\subseteq \overline{M}$. So $x\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}\subseteq \overline{U}\cap\overline M \text{ and thus }x\in  Int(\overline{U\cap M}) $ ( since $W_{1}\cap W_{2}$ is open).

I probably made a mistake somewhere in the second part since I never used that U is open, but I can't find it (I have seen a counterexample why it doesnt hold if U isn't open).

Comment: You showed that $Int(\bar U) \cap Int(\bar M) \subseteq Int(\bar U \cap \bar M)$, not $Int(\overline{U \cap M})$.

Comment: I have a long one line plain text proof that is too tedius to transcribe into  Math Jaxov script.  Would you like to read it as is?

Comment: Yes, plese. I tried to see if x is interior point for U or in the frontier of U, and in the first case I think i can finish it, not sure about the second one though.

Comment: @user3701033 Ok, I will send it out tonight with needed explainations.

Comment: @user3701033  It is too much of a hassle to post my answer with proper formatting at this site.  I will post it at an easy to use, old fashion web site, late tonight or tomorrow evening.

Comment: @user3701033.  Ok, I found the work around to post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int A is interior of A;  cl A is closure of A.
A /\ B is A intersection B;  A \/ B is A union B
This is part of an efficient plain text language in use
before the inefficient Math Jaxov monopolized math talk.

Lemma.  If U is open, then U /\ cl A subset cl (U /\ A).
This is a very useful lemma that allows 'algebraic' proofs
instead of point proofs as you were attempting.  A point
proof, which I leave for you, is needed to prove the lemma.

open A implies int cl A/\B = int cl A /\ int cl B
Proof.  Uses the lemma twice.

int cl A/\B subset int (cl A /\ cl B) = int cl A /\ int cl B
subset int (cl A /\ int cl B) subset int cl (A /\ int cl  B)
subset int cl (A /\ cl B) subset int cl cl A/\B = int cl A/\B

Immediately, by complementation, one has the topological dual
closed A implies cl int A\/B = cl int A \/ cl int B.

A is regular open when A = int cl A.
Exercise.  Show int cl A is regular open and the
intersection of two regular open sets is regular open.

Note that in your problem all the sets involved are regular
open.  However the problem, though similar, isn't as simple
as the intersection of regular open sets is regular open.

Comment: subset int (cl A /\ int cl B) subset int cl (A /\ int cl ordered B) what does "cl ordered B" mean and how do we obtain that inclusion?

Comment: what i mean is, the inclusion $int(\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B})\subseteq int(\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B})$  We have that $int\overline{B}=int\overline{(int\overline{B})}$ because $int\overline{B}$ is regular open, but we can obtain from there that $int(\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B})=int(\overline{A}\cap \overline{int\overline{B}})$ and we can't use the lemma in that case, what did I miss

Comment: @user3701033 ordered means that computers do dumb stupid things behind your back.  I removed that to undo the auto puckthink.

Comment: Still don't get how $int\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B} \subseteq int(\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B})$

Comment: Ah, $int\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B} =int(int\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\subseteq int(\overline{A}\cap int\overline{B})$

Comment: @user3701033.  I am not following what you are doing.   The stated inclusion is actually an equality.   The int cl int cl stuff is off tract.  The lemma is used on cl A /\ int cl B and A /\ cl B.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you get that :  int cl A /\ int cl B
subset int (cl A /\ int cl B) (copied from what you wrote) I think it follows from what I wrote

Comment: It is a subset of cl A /\ int cl B and as it is open, it is a subset of the interior thereof.  @user3701033